# How to add to my search views, option to search by `Category` name?

Tags: django

How to add to my search views, option to search by `Category` name also?

**models:**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
```

**views:**

```
def search(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['search']
        if len(term) > 5:
            d = Document.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=term) | Q(
                content__contains=term))
            count = d.count()
            return render_to_response('search_result.html', {'d': d,'term':term, 'count': count}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('search_result.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You can use a `RelatedSearchQuerySet` https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#relatedsearchqueryset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
d = Document.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=term) | Q(
            content__contains=term) | Q(category__name__contains=term))
```

Here is the relevant documentation on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Yes. You can . I was trying to look up for the relevant documentation. :)

Comment: i was always writing an extra loop and another query ... something new that i learnt ..